# Automatically run nodejs code on Insert [Mongo DB]

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongo DB but I would like to find out if it is possible to run a nodejs script everytime a document is inserted into mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "change streams" or "notifications API".

See [this article](https://emptysqua.re/blog/driver-features-for-mongodb-3-6/#change-streams) for details. It's in Python but should be able to understand it and apply it to NodeJS.